# Opposite of the word "specific"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Literally speaking "unspecific" is the opposite of "specific", though I don't think it fits my intended use well.

Math is an abstract concept. There is nothing physical about math. Though it is very abstract, it is still very specific in the sense that everything is very well defined. What word could be used to describe something that is the opposite of the specificity math has? I'm looking for words similar to "open ended" or "loosey-goosey".

Another example would be how politicians tend to talk in vague terms without specifics.

Comment: General, vague, generalized, generalization, variable (in the math sense)

Comment: _Childish_ is the word you want; the specificity of math is opposed to its lack among children and others whose minds are not accustomed to keeping dozens of axioms satisfied simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General**

> 5. not specific or definite:
>      <sub>-[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/general)</sub>

This would be like:

"Politicians tend to talk in general terms without specifics."

Answer (score 1):

You used the word **vague** yourself, that's a good start.

The usual opposite of **specific** is **non-specific**. **Inspecific** or **unspecific** can be read to suggest some specification that's incomplete. **Non-specific** suggests a lack of intention towards any specificity.

Other words you could use are **ethereal**, **fuzzy**, **rough** or **loose**.

Comment: Yes. It's a technical term in linguistics. English has both specific and non-specific indefinite nouns. For instance, in _She's looking for a policeman, but she can't find him,_ the indefinite noun phrase _a policeman_ is **specific**, because _him_ refers to a specific person. But in _She's looking for a policeman, but she can't find one,_ it's **non-specific**, because _one_ doesn't refer to a specific person.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'random' as an antonym.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of programming, when we aren't working with something that has been specified, we are usually working with something **generic** or **abstract**.
so those two words are also an option, i guess.